# PHP transaction are not working on my wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I want to upload some data in my table which is innoDB but every time I want to clean the data stored in the table, so i run a truncate command to do this. But if my insert query goes false then I want that table to get rollback. Below code does not work for me. Am I missing something? Someone help me on this please?

```
function begin() {
    mysql_query("BEGIN");
}

function commit() {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
}

function rollback() {
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}

begin();
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name");

if(mysql_query("Any bad insert query"))
{
    commit();
}
else
{
    rollback();
}
```

Comment: Logic suggests you're committing on `Any bad insert query` and rolling back on success.... is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @MarkBaker I think you got confused.

Comment: So `if(mysql_query("Any bad insert query"))
{
    commit();
}` is confusing me... that suggests commit on `Any bad insert query`

Comment: If that query is successful then commit, otherwise rollback.

Comment: Bad insert query means there may be any error in that query which will never run. It means "mysql_query("Any bad insert query")" will return false and data should get rollback. Code is right.

Comment: @Shakeel Just a sanity check. You appear to be using the `mysql_*` php extension. That extension does not support `Transaction processing`, so your `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` may run without error, but will have no effect as the `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE etc` will already have been committed! Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: No it supports and I got the answer i.e., TRUNCATE TABLE causes implicit commit (i.e. it can't be rolled back). Use DELETE instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` causes [implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html) (i.e. it can't be rolled back). Use `DELETE` instead.

Comment: I replaced TRUNCATE to DELETE But DELETE does not reset auto increment field to 1. I wrote mysql_query("ALTER TABLE temple_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1"); after DELETE statement but it did not work.

Comment: Becasue `ALTER TABLE` also causes implicit commit (it's right there, in the link I gave you). I am sorry, but with current MySQL version you can't reset `AUTO_INCREMENT` within a transaction.